# refresh h selectonmenu in jsp panel by using javascript on load

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, jsf-1.2

I have a rich table panel with many panels containing a jsp file.
I have one jsp file like this :

```
<rich:panel>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Traitement" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <table style="width: 95%; border-spacing: 5px">

    <tr>
        <td><h:outputLabel value="Fruit list  : " /></td>
        <td>
          <h:selectOneMenu
                    id="list_fruit" style="width:288px;"
                    value="#{myBean.FruitId}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue = "1" itemLabel = "fruit 1" /> 
                <f:selectItem itemValue = "2" itemLabel = "fruit 2" /> 
                <f:selectItem itemValue = "3" itemLabel = "fruit 3" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    </h:panelGroup>
</rich:panel>
```

My problem is when i select fruit1 or fruit2 or fruit3  and i click in another panel and when i return to this panel, i have the last select present(fruit1 or fruit2 or fruit3).
I want to empty user selection when I go to another panel and i return to thius panel, the select choice must have empty.
How can i do refresh my jsp page side javascript to delete the last select of fruit and the selection by default must have empty

Answer (score 0):

The value is held in `#{myBean.FruitId}`. You have to clear this value.

You can put a `a4j:jsFunction` or a `<p:remoteCommand` in your panel and call this function from your javascript `onblur`, `onfocus` or `onclick` method.
This way, you can call any bean method and do a value setting as you want. Don't forget to give the remoteCommand a correct `update="mypanelid"`